# Json String can't decode using json-simple toolkit java

Tags: java, json, exception, decode, json-simple

[JSON-Simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

[JSON-Simple Example](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples)

```
String login = "{\"result\":[104192,42068],\"id\":1}";

Object obj = JSONValue.parse(login);

JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
```

This throw a exception

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be
>   cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

What is the problem in this code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case the parsed result is a `JSONObject` so you need to cast it to that.

Comment: What if the JSONObject is used as an object elsewhere? Why is the cast on assignment not enough?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast an object into an array. Try adding the object to the array instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I have fixed it. Here is my code snippet:

```
Object obj = JSONValue.parse(response.getBody());
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
Object gu_obj = jsonObject.get("guid");
```

I got the yahoo user guid from the request body. Hope this helps :)